# UICollection View not reloading after changing the Array from a button click (button is outside UI Collection view)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am very new to swift. So TLDR I have a collection view which I want to update after I click a button. I have seen various solutions and everyone suggesting to put collectionView.reloadData but I am not understanding where to put this line in my code. Any help will be appreciated.
This is the view controller:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var charList: Array<String> = []
    
    var data: String = ""
    
    var songTiles = [
        "teri meri": ["D", "A", "G", "A", "F", "G", "A", "F", "G", "A", "G", "F", "E", "D", "E", "D", "C", "D", "E", "F", "E", "F", "E", "G", "A", "G", "F", "E", "D", "D"],
        "faded": ["B", "A", "B", "A"],
        "darmiyan": ["A", "B", "B", "A"],
        "hangover": ["B", "A", "B", "A"],
        "dna": ["A", "A", "A", "A"],
        "fire": ["A", "B", "B", "A"],
        "springday": ["C", "A", "A", "A"],
        "gotcha": ["C", "A", "A", "A"],
        "aurora": ["C", "A", "A", "A"],
        "fadedremix": ["A", "B", "A", "B"]
    ]
    
    @IBOutlet weak var chosenSong: UILabel!


    @IBAction func keyNote(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender.currentTitle == charList[0]) {
            charList.removeFirst()
            print("Correct!")
            playSound(sound: sender.currentTitle!)
        }
    }
    
    func playSound(sound: String) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound, withExtension: "wav") else {
            return

        }
        do {
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
                    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        
                    player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url, fileTypeHint: AVFileType.mp3.rawValue)
        
                    guard let player = player else { return }
        
                    player.play()
        
                } catch let error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
    }
    
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        charList = songTiles[data]!
        chosenSong.text = data

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    
}
 

extension myViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {
    
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return charList.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        myCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

        let cell = myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! myCollectionViewCell
        cell.myImage.image = UIImage(named: charList[indexPath.row])
        myCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

        
        return cell
    }
    
    
}
```

So the way this code works is it deletes the character from the start of the array that user has selected each time user presses the button correctly.
For eg if I choose Array Faded and I press A the Array in the UIControllerView should remove A and update collection view accordingly. Think of it as a tutorial of learning songs on xylophone.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
@IBAction func keyNote(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender.currentTitle == charList[0]) {
            charList.removeFirst()
            print("Correct!")
            
            let theIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)   
            myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [theIndex])
            playSound(sound: sender.currentTitle!)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Adding this line the code worked for the first element but subsequently it crashed. However I changed It to this it worked:
`let theIndex = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
  myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [theIndex])`
Thanks for your help

Comment: Actually i answered about the place where you should add reloadData.. Btw I am updating my answer.

Comment: PS. Also you need to remove the myCollectionView.reloadData() as there is no need of it after using myCollectionView.deleteItems() and somehow my app is crashing by using myCollectionView.reloadData().

Answer (score 0):

Don't call `reloadItems(at: [indexPath])` in `cellForItemAt:indexPath` - the collection view is in the middle of asking you for the cell there, reload items will make it ask you again.

You need to tell the collection view it needs to ask you again when your model charList changes: here: `charList.removeFirst()`